# Reading multiple excel sheets into separate data frames then append with sheets from another excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, loops, append, rbind

I am trying to read multiple excel sheets of an excel file into separate dataframes in R. I have 31 sheets. So I tried this:

```
setwd('E:/Report_folder')
x1_data <- 'E:/Report_folder/report_1h.xlsx'
sheets <- excel_sheets(x1_data)
book <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:31){
book <- read_excel(path = x1_data, sheet = i)
  names(book) <- sheets[i]
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Can someone tell me why?

I also have multiple excel files with same sheet names and format, and I want to append all the sheets with similar names and formats in different excel files into separate data frames. Shall I use a loop to read each sheet in those excel files, then append to the associated sheet of the first excel file?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you want to append. I think you want to create a dataset for each excel sheet? is that it?

Comment: Have you tried the example code in readxl::excel_sheets documentation: `?excel_sheets`: `lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)`. In your case replace `path` with `x1_data`

Comment: I actually tried list2env(x1_data, .GlobalEnv) and it makes separate sheets into separate data frames. But I also want to append the similarly formatted sheets from other excel files into the sheets of the master file. So far no luck :(